# what type of iterator to require in a template function?

Tags: c++, stl, iterator

I am making my own sort() algorithm based on counting sort. It sorts positive numbers that are range limited. So far it works on std::string and std::vector.

The prototype is as follows:

```
template<class ForwardIterator, int maxNumbers>
void sortIntegers(ForwardIterator start, ForwardIterator end)
```

My algorithm uses `*iter =`, `++iter` and `copy = iter`. From http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/iterator/ I determined I need a ForwardIterator or better.

Is that the correct way to determine the most generic type of iterator my algorithm requires? I'm not sure I should be trying to be generic. I just guessed I should. This way I could support the most number of containers. Then when I looked at the STL sort(), I see that it uses Random Access Iterator (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/). To me that means it is limited on what containers it supports. For instance, would it work on list?

I figure STL is doing it right. So why am I wrong to only require ForwardIterator in my function? Maybe as I test more container types, I will realize I need to be more restrictive?

Also as a bonus, I know that just naming the class type as ForwardIterator is only a documentation requirement. Does STL do more to ensure what is passed in to sort() is a Random Access Iterator? So if I passed in a list iterator to sort(), I assume I get errors. How do those errors get generated?

Comment: I'd recommend using the [en.cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator) rather than that unreliably cplusplus.com stuff.

Comment: `std::sort` requires random access because `qsort` requires random access.

Comment: `std::sort` doesn't work with `std::list`, but `std::list` supplies its own version, as member function `std::list::sort`.

Comment: You could add a SFINAE check to ensure that the iterator (at least) identifies itself as being a forward iterator: `template <class ForwardIterator, int Max, class = std::enable_if_t<std::is_base_of<std::forward_iterator_tag, typename std::iterator_traits<ForwardIterator>::iterator_category>::value>> ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is that the correct way to determine the most generic type of iterator my algorithm requires?

Well, yes. Looking at the concepts and determining which iterator concept your algorithm requires is the right way to go.

> To me that means it is limited on what containers it supports. For instance, would it work on list?

No, it wouldn't work on `std::list`, because `std::list` only has support for the BidirectionalIterator concept, which RandomAccessIterator derives from. Yes, because of that it is limited on certain containers.

> So why am I wrong to only require ForwardIterator in my function?

It's not wrong, but you are limited, i.e. you can't use `--it` for example, but if that is fine, then there is nothing wrong with it. C++ just wants to give the implementation as much freedom as possible I figure.

> Does STL do more to ensure what is passed in to sort() is a Random Access Iterator?

No, there is no protection. The only thing is that if you call it with not a RandomAccessIterator, you will get an error (or multiple), because your iterator doesn't support the operations `std::sort` requires (like `[]`, `--`, ...).

There is a TS for Concepts, which would do exactly that, enforce compile-time requirements on template parameters, and produce a useful error message when you are using the wrong type. But that is probably coming in for C++20.

You could also make a trait check to check the tag of iterators, as @JustinTime suggested, but that is sadly not required by the Standard, so no or very few implementations actually do that (I know none, so I can't be sure about that).

Comment: It's easy enough to define a [trait check for iterator tags](http://ideone.com/Fc9ncr).  `check_iter()` could also be rewritten to take a tag to check for as a template parameter, and to determine `UseIteratorTraits` with preprocessor magic.

Comment: @JustinTime Jup, although I wouldn't exactly call it "easy" :) Thanks

Comment: You're welcome.  Changed it to be more generic, and put in an example of how to use it.  The `static_assert` in the function itself is redundant, but allows it to be used either in another `static_assert` or in a `bool` template parameter.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you *aren't* requiring the parameters to be `ForwardIterator`s here.

You see, `template<class ForwardIterator, int maxNumbers>` means that the template accepts two parameters: one of them is a class and the other is just an integer. Notice that *no requirements or restrictions* are imposed on the kind of that class. C++ *does not* care about the name of a parameter *that much*, it cares more about types.